# How to run a Apache Beam pipeline using a Flink runner in application mode?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, apache-beam

I'm trying to run a beam pipeline using Flink as the runner deployed using Native Kubernetes application mode but I'm unable to configure Beam on how to use the Flink interface in application mode.

Since Flink is deployed in application mode, there isn't a master manager node up and running to receive new jobs. Specifically, the [docs for Beam to use the Flink runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/#executing-a-beam-pipeline-on-a-flink-cluster) on a separate cluster needs a `flink-master` URL which I don't have.

> Start JobService with Flink Rest endpoint: `docker run --net=host apache/beam_flink1.10_job_server:latest --flink-master=localhost:8081`

To run Flink jobs in native k8s application mode, a command like this is executed:

```
./bin/flink run-application \
    --target kubernetes-application \
    -Dkubernetes.cluster-id=my.cluster.id \
    -Dkubernetes.container.image=custom-docker-image \
    -Dkubernetes.rest-service.exposed.type=ClusterIP \
    -Dkubernetes.pod-template-file.jobmanager=/path/to/jobmanager/template \
    -Dkubernetes.pod-template-file.taskmanager=/path/to/taskmanager/template \
    local:///opt/flink/usrlib/job.jar
```

Is there a way to have Beam not use the `flink-master` url but instead build the complete job jar and submit it to Kubernetes as a Flink application in the form of such a command?

Comment: Is your Beam pipeline written in Java or Python?

Comment: It's in Python.